# Sharepoint : Accesing a file by its name from a .NET app. Over 5000 items isue. Need an index by file "Name" column?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, caml

I am developing a .net application to process information in sharepoint.
There are over 5000 items in the sharepoint library I work with.

I wrote a CAML filter to handle the >5000 items problem. It works fine when I use the "Modified" column to filter, but if I use the "Name" column instead, I keep getting the > 5000 error message.

example1:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified'/><Value Type='DateTime'>2020-11-02T15:08:15Z</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>"
```

example2:

```
 'camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/><Value Type='Text'>002-000000.pdf</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>"
```

The only difference I see is that "Modified" is an indexed column .
I tried to create an indez for "Name" column with the sharepoint online menu, but this column name ("Name" nor "LinkFilename" ) doesn't apear between the posibilities.

How can I create an Index for "Name" column? .

thanks

Comment: SharePoint isn't a database. *Don't* retrieve 5000 items to begin with. Write a query that only returns what you need. What are you trying to do? Find new files? Why? There's a new item indicator already. Export new files to some other system?

Comment: You can improve performance immensely if you only retrieve specific fields, or don't retrieve items at all, using `SPList.GetDataTable` to retrieve a DataTable with field values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using an **id** so that u can keep track of how many items u r retrieving in each call.

Answer (score 0):

Not all column could be indexed. Please check below docs to see 'Supported and unsupported columns for indexing':

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0

To overcome list view threshold error, please take a reference below blog:

- https://natechamberlain.com/2018/05/21/how-to-resolve-sharepoint-list-view-threshold-error-the-view-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold/
- [CSOM pagination](https://thatlazyprogrammer.com/2014/06/10/client-object-model-access-large-listsovercome-listview-threshold-while-accessing-large-list/)

BR